# Get the library name from GUID in VBA

Tags: list, sql, vba, guid

I want to pull information from a SharePoint 2016 list in VBA. Below Code is what I found and that is working without depending on a view. Unfortunately the SQL query uses the list Name. A user could Change the list Name and then the Code would not work anymore. If I could read the list Name via GUID then the list could be renamed...

So I have three options:

1. Read the list name in VBA via GUID
2. Get a different VBA Code to pull Information without view or list Name
3. Write in the documentation not to change the library Name (lame!)

Conditions:

- I need to retrieve information from a SharePoint list via the item ID
- It has to be VBA
- If there is a better solution in SOAP or REST I also take it, but have no clue on how to...

Here the working VBA Code I found with MS ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 in References to pull list data:

```
' Some public constants, but they can be procedure Level

' if you don't think you're going to need them elsewhere.

Public Const sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID As String = "{012CFE06-DAD2-4294-AE45-2FD140D7BB55}"

Public Const sSHAREPOINT_SITE As String = "https://www.sharepoint.com/site/"

Sub TestPullFromSharepoint()

' This pulls the data from a SharePoint list. Don't forget a reference

' to the MS ActiveX Objects in "References".

' Variable declarations.

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Dim sConn As String

Dim sSQL As String

Dim ID As String

ID = 14 'as example

' Build the connection string: use the ACE engine, the database is the URL if your site

' and the GUID of your SharePoint list is the LIST.

sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _

"DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _

"LIST=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID & ";"

' Create some new objects.

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open the connection.

With cn

.ConnectionString = sConn

.Open

End With

' Build your SQL the way you would any other. You can add a WHERE clause

' if you need to filter on some criteria.

sSQL = "SELECT tbl.[name] FROM [Library Name] as tbl where tbl.[id] = 14"

' Open up the recordset.

rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

' Copy the recordset data to a worksheet.

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rs

 MsgBox rs(0)

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help